# Excel: Multiple If with Countif Statements

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel, I have three formulas/statements I'd like to merge into one.  I've listed the statements below.  Is there a way to merge all three formulas into one?  I'd like to learn how to write the logic to do this.  Thanks.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)=1, "MATCH")

=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)>1, "DUPLICATE")

=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)<1, "NO MATCH")
```

Answer (score 1):

The [syntax](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) of the `IF` function is `IF(true-false-condition, value-if-condition-true, value-if-condition-false)` (where either missing `value-if` defaults to `0`).

3-way (or more) `IF` conditionals can be written by nesting multiple boolean `IF`'s, for example:

```
    =IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)>1, "DUPLICATE", IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)=1, "MATCH", "NO MATCH"))
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply because the logic you provided was very helpful.  Your formula works very well.  I found using the following formula also helped me find what I was looking for:  =IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)>1, "DUPLICATE", IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)=1, "MATCH", IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)<1, "NO MATCH")))

Comment: @YellaBandit That will work, too, though the last `IF` is redundant in this case. You are comparing two numbers `a`, `b`, so if `a > b` and `a = b` are both false, then the only case left is `a < b`.

Comment: You're right.  This makes sense.  Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider good practice  of trapping the default 'else' case. The above answer does not do this, and it assumes your input will always be one of your stated cases (=1, <1 or >1) so omits the final IF condition. In that example this will not error because the evaluations will always return `true` or `false`, but this may not behave as expected if an input is a different data type, null set, etc. In the stated answer, this unexpected behaviour will "fail silently" which is a potential issue.

Instead, try:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)>1, "DUPLICATE", IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)=1, "MATCH", IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)<1, "NO MATCH", "ERROR")))
```

In implementation you would replace "ERROR" with your chosen error handling method.

You could also look at the following Excel functions, as an alternative to nesting multiple IF functions:

**SWITCH:**

```
=SWITCH(expression, value1, result1, [default or value2, result2],…[default or value3, result3])
```

**IFS:**

```
=IFS (test1, value1, [test2, value2], ...)
```

Some of these are newer than others so be sure to test to your version of Excel (and consider compatibility with any other possible users of your file).

Comment: YellaBandit I see that you have done similar, by your comment above. @dxiv this may be true for this use case, but not necessarily - see above.