# Join Multiple IF/COUNTIF Statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are two columns of data being used in the formula.

```
Time      Origination                    RESULTS DESIRED
1:00 pm    Buffalo Grove, MI                12:00 pm
3:00 pm    Hayward, IN                       2:00 pm
7:40 am    Las Vegas, NV                     9:40 am
11:15 am    Chicago, IL                     11:15 am
```

I need a formula to return a modified "Time" for records where the origination is MI, IN or NV.

The formula I have so far subtracts 1 hour from the MI or IN records, which is what I want.  I need to expand on that formula to add 2 hours to the NV records.  The formula criteria have to be wildcards.

Formula so far:

```
IF(OR(COUNTIF(H2,"*, IN*"),COUNTIF(H2,"*, MI*")),B2-TIME(1,0,0),B2)
```

This works perfectly for the MI and IN records

I need to add this to the above formula:

```
IF(COUNTIF(H2,"*, NV*"),B2+TIME(2,0,0),B2)
```

I tried the following formulas, but they return "The formula you typed contains an error."

In the case of the Stack Overflow formula, the cursor points to the first * in the statement in the formula window.

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(H2,"*, IN*"),COUNTIF(H2,"*, MI*")),B2-TIME(1,0,0),B2),IF(OR(COUNTIF(H2,"*, NV*"),B2+TIME(2,0,0),B2))
```

This formula is from a post on your site at the following URL ([Excel: Multiple If with Countif Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542633/excel-multiple-if-with-countif-statements))
I tried to it modify as follows:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($H:$H,$H2)=”*, IN*”, B2-TIME(1,0,0), IF(COUNTIF($H:$H,$H2)=”*, MI*”, B2-TIME(1,0,0), IF(COUNTIF($H:$H,$H2)=”*, NV*”, B2+TIME(2,0,0), B2)))
```

I am working with Excel for Mac 2011.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Would you provide more details on how is obtained the desired result in the question? How it correlates with Time, it seems some additional information is needed to understand the logic. Thanks

Comment: The "Results Desired" is a mockup of what answers should result from the formula requested.  "The Formula so far:" that I listed above works perfectly on those records with the states of IN (Indiana) and MI (Michigan).Basically, for records of IN and MI subtract and hour from the TIME, add 2 hours to the records with NV and do nothing for the records with IL.  I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank @NLN, check my answer assuming there are no Excel version constraints per tag listed in your question. And let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `COUNTIF` you could use a combination of `FIND` and `NOT` to search for the state abbreviations.

This is quite a long formula but there are probably a few ways it could be adjusted.

```
=A2+IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("IN",B2))),NOT(ISERROR(FIND("MI",B2)))),-TIME(1,0,0),IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("NV",B2))),TIME(2,0,0),0))
```

It's also possible a different approach might be possible if assumptions can be made about the data, for example will the state abbreviation always be at the end?

Comment: Thank you, Norie!

The formula worked perfectly within a limited sampling of data that I was using to test formulas.

My only concern is what happens if the formula comes across a combination of letters "mi", "Mi" or "in" or "In" or "nv" or "Nv" in the body of the town.  This was why I used the comma and space in front of the state abbreviations.  Or is the formula case sensitive?

One item of note, "IN" was included in your formula twice so I changed the second "IN" to "MI".

To answer your question about the state abbreviation, yes it is always at the end.

Comment: And finally, I am still curious though if it is possible to join another IF/COUNTIF statement to my first one.  

For future reference, since the IF function doesn't allow wildcards. And since my level of Excel understanding is fairly basic, I personally found the IF/COUNTIF formula easier to follow.

Again, I truly appreciate your time and expertise.  Thank you.

Comment: Will the state abbreviation always be at the end?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do some timezone conversion, I would suggest using a lookup table for a more general case. For example:

```
=A2:A5+XLOOKUP(TEXTAFTER(B2:B5,", ",-1),{"IN","MI","NV","IL"}, {-1,-1,2,0})/24
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

it uses `TEXTAFTER` to extract the state by doing a reverse search, then to find the corresponding time diff via `XLOOKUP` and add to the **Time** column value. One hour duration is represented in Excel as `1/24`.

Comment: Unfortunately, Excel for Mac 2011 does not include the XLOOKUP or the TEXTAFTER functions.  I looked up alternatives and there is VLOOKUP but based on research, that has some drawbacks.

Comment: I see @NLN next time please specify in the tag list your specific Excel version, so the solutions provided consider your requirements.

Comment: @NLN I have a mac what I use is Excel Web, which is free, so I don't have such limitations. You have all the Excel functions you need, except `FILTERXML`

Comment: Appreciate the advice re my Excel version, I included it in the body, but next time I will add it to the tag line where it is more readily seen.  Regarding Excel Web, from what I understand VBA is not available and I do have some workbooks with VBA but thank you for the suggestion.